# show dialog in PrimeFaces based on value in bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` which is displayed by `oncomplete` of a commandButton

```
<p:commandButton value="Update" id="update"
    actionListener="#{serviceTypeViewBean.beforeUpdate}"
    oncomplete="updatedlg.show();)">
</p:commandButton>
```

This dialog has a list which is updated in the 'beforeUpdate' method. I want to add a condition in the oncomplete that if the list is not empty show the dialog

```
if(list != empty){
 updatedlg.show()
};
```

How to add this condition in the oncomplete of commandButton?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as @Xtreme Biker suggested. The other solution is to use callbackParam:

Add to your `beforeUpdate` method code like the following:

```
if(list != empty){
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("emptyList", false);
} else {
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("emptyList", true);
}
```

Then you can check the param in your `oncomplete` attribute like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Update" id="update"
    actionListener="#{serviceTypeViewBean.beforeUpdate}"
    oncomplete="if(!args.emptyList) { PF('updatedlg').show(); }">
</p:commandButton>
```

Please notice that callbackParam is flexible and you can find usage for it in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL evaluation in order to render/hide javascript code:

`oncomplete=#{not empty serviceTypeViewBean.list ? 'updatedlg.show()' : '' }`

**See also:**

- [Need help Using EL in javascript to get value from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843401/need-help-using-el-in-javascript-to-get-value-from-model)